# How to loop through an array to display values on a chart using SwiftUI and Swift Charts

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, charts

Using SwiftUI and Swift Charts I am trying to create a chart, from a model so that a chart appears individually within a view composed of sample data from the model.

Here is my model:

```
import Foundation

struct VerticalBarChart: Identifiable, Hashable {
  let id: UUID
  var image: String
  var title: String
  var xValue: [String]
  var yValue: [Int]
  var dateCreated: Date
}

extension VerticalBarChart {
  static var sampleData: [VerticalBarChart] {
    [
      VerticalBarChart(
        id: UUID(),
        image: "chart.bar",
        title: "Vertical Bar Chart 1",
        xValue: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "friday"],
        yValue: [500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
        dateCreated: Date.now),
      VerticalBarChart(
        id: UUID(),
        image: "chart.bar",
        title: "Vertical Bar Chart 2",
        xValue: ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 3"],
        yValue: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        dateCreated: Date.now),
      VerticalBarChart(
        id: UUID(),
        image: "chart.bar",
        title: "Vertical Bar Chart 3",
        xValue: ["Wednesday"],
        yValue: [700],
        dateCreated: Date.now)
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is my view code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct VerticalBarChartView: View {
  
  var verticalBarChart: VerticalBarChart

  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      
      
      Chart {
        ForEach(VerticalBarChart.sampleData) { element in
          BarMark(
            x: .value("x-axis", element.xValue),
            y: .value("y-axis", element.yValue)
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to correct / write code so that the view displays data from only one chart per view containing data from only one dataset of xValue and yValue. Ideally I would like to display three charts on three separate views created from the sample data.

For example, the first chart should be created from:

```
xValue: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "friday"],
yValue: [500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Tony.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MARK: -  variable

var ydata = VerticalBarChart.sampleData.first!.yValue
var xdata = VerticalBarChart.sampleData.first!.xValue
var chartData: [(String, Int)] {
    Array(zip(xdata,ydata))
}
```

```
//MARK: - view
    
var body: some View {
    List {
        Chart(chartData, id: \.0 ) { item in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("x-axis", item.0),
                y: .value("y-axis", item.1)
            )
        }
        .frame(height: 250)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation why this is a good answer.